# android scrollview animation

Tags: android, animation, android-layout, scrollview, scroller

I am trying to animate a Scrollview. 
Particularly the SmoothScrollTo(x,y) function. Any ideas on how I go about this.
Thanks

```
 ScrollView scroller = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroller);
 if(true){
       scroller.smoothScrollTo(0,30);
       animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.down);
       anim.setFillAfter(true);
       scroller.startAnimation(anim);


 } else{
           .....
 }
```

Comment: Scrollview always scroll and why do u want to animate it?

Comment: I want to control the speed of the scrollTo function. So I am thinking that I could do that through animation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve smooth scrolling there is no need to animate the scroll.
Use reflection to set up your own custom Scroller & Interpolator.

something like this:

```
Field mScroller;
mScroller = ScrollView.class.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
mScroller.setAccessible(true);

CustomScroller scroller = new CustomScroller(getContext(), new AccelerateInterpolator());
mScroller.set(this, scroller);
```

Surround Try/Catch & there u go.

user smoothScrollTo method.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure whether you add animation to the scroller. I maybe wrong. One method would be to use the Timer and TimerTask to schedule a task to increment/decrement the scrollTo values.
You can vary the interval in which the task executes to speedup and slow down the scrolling.